# TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined at getAssignmentTargetKind

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-cli-v7

This problem started to occur when updating my Angular 6 project to 7.x.

I opened an issue on the angular-cli github repo but they couldn't help.

So what I did is create a new project and add all components one by one to "hopefully" notice what caused the problem.

Unfortunately I couldn't identify the problem. Here's the log:

```
ERROR in : TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
at getAssignmentTargetKind (E:\McClient\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:10049:28)
at Object.isAssignmentTarget (E:\McClient\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:10092:16)
at checkObjectLiteral (E:\McClient\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:46107:45)
at checkExpressionWorker (E:\McClient\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:50748:28)
at checkExpression (E:\McClient\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:50696:42)
at checkExpressionWithContextualType (E:\McClient\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:50524:26)
at checkApplicableSignature (E:\McClient\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:47963:35)
at chooseOverload (E:\McClient\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:48281:26)
at resolveCall (E:\McClient\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:48231:26)
at resolveCallExpression (E:\McClient\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:48534:20)
at resolveSignature (E:\McClient\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:48800:28)
at getResolvedSignature (E:\McClient\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:48844:26)
at checkCallExpression (E:\McClient\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:48936:29)
at checkExpressionWorker (E:\McClient\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:50759:28)
at checkExpression (E:\McClient\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:50696:42)
at resolveDecorator (E:\McClient\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:48741:28)
```

Here's a link to the github issue with logs from a checkSourcefile function I was supposed to log:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13172

How can I track down and (hopefully) fix what's causing this?

Edit: My ng --version info

```
Angular CLI: 7.1.3
Node: 8.11.4
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.1.3
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.11.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.11.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.11.3
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.11.3
@angular-devkit/core              7.1.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.1.3
@angular/cdk                      7.1.1
@ngtools/webpack                  7.1.3
@schematics/angular               7.1.3
@schematics/update                0.11.3
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.1.6
webpack                           4.23.1
```

Comment: Please ensure that you've followed all the steps shown here for migration - https://update.angular.io/ and then try to delete all your node_modules & reinstall them using `npm install`

Comment: I tried this already - no luck

Answer (score 17):

I simply re-run

```
    ng serve
```

again and it worked!

Comment: Well yes. But it's annoying to do that ~50 times a day. Still looking for an actual fix

Comment: This solved for me too and just a note: Error started happening to me when i added custom javascript code to my Angular app (Typescript)

Comment: This is answer is works. But couldn't found the actual root cause why this error occurred. In my case I am facing after every 1 or 2 hours while developing while ng serve is running.

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with the same problem, did some digging and found 2 major solutions:

1. Installing '@types/history' package.
2. Downgrading typescript to 3.1.6(since the bug wasn't occurring
   then).

See this GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28810).

Answer (score 4):

**Run the application again using** `ng serve` and it fixed the issue for me.
It happened when I pulled code from a branch to my existing running branch which was running via ng serve.

Answer (score 4):

**Disclaimer:** this is not a good "fix", but it will get the job done if you're in a pinch. This is an issue related to the Angular devkit and build optimizer and has to do with version mismatches.

I ran into this problem and found a workaround in the case that upgrading Angular or other NPM packages isn't the ideal option to get things working immediately. [This comment on Github](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4-angular/issues/78#issuecomment-562535537) pointed me in the right direction. In the file `./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/transforms/scrub-file.js` in your project directory, there is a function called `isAngularDecoratorMetadataExpression` somewhere around line 237 (depending on the version you have). It has the following code toward the bottom of the function:

```
// Check second array entry for __metadata call.
if (decorateArray.elements[1].kind !== ts.SyntaxKind.CallExpression) {
  return false;
}
```

If you add this code just above those lines and save the file, it will bypass the problem:

```
// Workaround for missing metadata.
if(!decorateArray.elements[1]) {
  return false;
}
```

And after you have done that, run this command to try building your project again:

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --build-optimizer
```

Comment: This is just workaround. Have u found solution for this?

Comment: This is a good enough fix for me. Project is in the toilet and I could care less to fix this being that the project is in NG6 and we have a replacement in the works using 11.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem. I solved it by updating my local @angular/cli to the same version as the @anguluar/cli version in my project .

Answer (score 2):

It solved from version

> npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.7 -s

check this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-angular

Answer (score 2):

- I was having issue with while migrating ionic application  from V4 to V5.
- This is my error log image.

[image]

- It was fixed with the below solution.

https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4-angular/issues/78#issuecomment-565803253

Answer (score 2):

In my case downgrading @angular-builders/custom-webpack from version `10.0.1` to version `10.0.0` in package.json worked.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue, and it turns out that `@angular-devkit/build-angular` was in `devDependencies` when I was trying to build for prod – so moving that to `dependencies` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I tried to run the angular application in production mode

I tried this  `npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular` and it helped

Answer (score 1):

Updating the typescript devDependency from 3.9.0 to 4.0.3 and running ng g c [directory-name] --skip-import

Comment: The above solution works perfectly when the error occurred is "Option "entryComponent" is deprecated: Since version 9.0.0 with Ivy, entryComponents is no longer necessary. cannot read property "kind" of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I had abstract classes with @Injectable, removing it solved the issue.

Hopes it helps

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while building application, i modified build configurations in angular.json it worked!!

```
{
  ...
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      budgets: [
        "initial": true,
        minimum: 5mb,
        maximum: 8mb
      ],
      "common-chunk": true
      "vendor-chunk": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the `serve` command was working fine, but the `build` command gave the error.

The error was, since we were using a custom builder '`@angular-builders/custom-webpack`'. The version of this package caused the issue.

Once I installed the correct version of this package as per our angular version, the issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally got to solve this by adding --poll 1000 when running ng serve:

ng serve --poll 1000