# ng build throws "ERROR in Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-cli, ng-build, angular-devkit

So I have a project I am working on that needs me to use `ng build --prod` to build a client. When I run `ng build --prod` I get the same error every time:

`ERROR in Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined`

This error occurs every time and no matter what I do, I cannot seem to get the client to build properly after nearly a week wrestling with it, and days searching for a solution. I have attached a git link to the client in hopes someone will be able to find and fix this error. To run this, just `npm install` in the Cube folder in the location you've downloaded it, then run `ng build --prod`. My hope is that this is an easy fix.

Github link to install the client:

`https://github.com/detis46901/Cube.git`

EDIT 1:
I have looked at other questions on StackOverflow, such as the one listed in the comment below ([TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined at getAssignmentTargetKind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53827570/typeerror-cannot-read-property-kind-of-undefined-at-getassignmenttargetkind)). These solutions do not seem to work.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53827570/typeerror-cannot-read-property-kind-of-undefined-at-getassignmenttargetkind

Comment: @Kinglish I have looked at that post before, and unfortunately none of those seem to be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution. I had to go in and edit the tsconfig.json.

Under `"angularCompilerOptions"` I had to add `"enableIvy": false`.

Under `"lib"` I had to add `"ES2020"` as well as `"ESNext"`.

Once I had done that, I then needed to `rm ./node_modules/` and then `npm i`. Then, I had to install specific versions of typescript and angular.

```
npm install typescript@3.6
npm install @angular-devkit/built-angular@0.901.9
npm install @angular/core@9.1.4 @angular/animations@9.1.4 @angular/common@9.1.4 @angular/forms@9.1.4 @angular/platform-browser@9.1.4 @angular/router@9.1.4 @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@9.1.4 @angular/compiler@9.1.4 @angular/compiler-cli@9.1.4 @angular/language-service@9.1.4
```

With these changes I was finally able to `ng build` the client. I will let the original github owner know what needs to change so that the program can be better used.